# C++ run project as standalone files, rather than a Code::Blocks project

Tags: c++

Good afternoon!

I'm currently working on a final project to close my first semester of C++ (and also programming in general) and I was wondering how I can properly link the implementation, header, and main files. The purpose is to be able to run them as just those 3 files, instead of being dependent on running them through a .project file.

This is an example of the project I'm doing:

Cat.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"

using namespace std;

void speak()
{
    cout << "meow" << endl;
}

void jump()
{
    cout << "meow?" << endl;
}
```

Cat.h

```
#ifndef CAT_H
#define CAT_H

void speak();
void jump();

#endif // CAT_H
```

CatMain.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    speak();
    jump();
    return 0;
}
```

The issue here is that when I open these files individually (without opening the .project file), I get the "undefined reference to WinMain@16" on Cat.cpp and "undefined reference" errors to the speak() and jump() functions on CatMain.cpp. The reason this might be an issue is because chances are that my professor won't have Code::Blocks to run it the same way as I do, so he will have to be able to run these standalone files rather than run the .project file.

Is there something I can do to link them together so that they're not dependent on the .project file to run properly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated =)

Comment: There should be a way to grab the linker command line from your IDE.  The linker command should use all of your compiled objects to create an executable program.  The error you are getting seems to imply you're not including your Cat.o object file when linking.

Comment: In case you're unaware, it's possible to build a C::B project from the commandline

Comment: Also, you should see what your professor **explicitly** requires from you for the assignment other than your source code.

Comment: Maybe either write a `makefile` or compile and link your source code files together using GNU GCC, which should be included with C::B.

Comment: From my searches I turned up something that looks like: "$ gcc -o output Cat.o CatMain.o". I just get the "$ does not name a type" error.

Comment: @BaloneyOs you should add the source file names as the arguments for gcc, not object files.

Comment: @BaloneyOs: The "$" represents a Linux terminal prompt. You're not supposed to include that in your command, only the stuff after it.

Comment: I see, so basically anyone can still run a program like this one as long as they know how. Good to know that I don't need to add anything to the files themselves, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

To run this or any C++ program without an IDE, you only need a C++ compiler available on the command line. (You may have to set an environment variable to the path to the compiler to use it on the command line)

To compile and run the code one could run the following commands on the command-line. (assuming a compiler such as GCC or MinGW, which uses the command `g++` to compile C++)

`g++ -c Cat.cpp` (produces an .o object file for the implementation of Cat.cpp and Cat.h)

`g++ CatMain.cpp Cat.o` (compiles the main function as an executable and links the Cat.o to it)

`a` (in windows cmd)

`./a.out` (on *nix systems)